# Core Updates after install with composer create-project drupal/drupal

Tags: 8, updating

So I installed Drupal with 
`composer create-project drupal/drupal <...>`

It works fine, but now I'm trying to update core from 8.4.1 to 8.4.4
What's the right way to do that? `composer update` only updates the modules, not core. 
How do I update core? I don't know that much about composer, but if I edit the composer.json and remove

```
"replace": {
    "drupal/core": "^8.4"
},
```

and add

```
"require": {
    "drupal/core": "^8.4",
    ...
 }
```

it seems to work.
Is this the right way to do this? If so, why is this not in the default composer.json, that comes with the project?

Answer (score 1):

You do in fact want to remove the drupal/core declaration (as it exists) in the *replace* section of composer.json, and then add the entry as you noted to the *require* section.  Then run `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies`.

You can find Drupal's official process for a Core upgrade with composer here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer-option-4