# Converting a drupal/drupal site to Work With Composer

Tags: 8, composer

At our company we have several sites that appear to have been made using the now deprecated method of `composer create-project drupal/drupal`. We've been fine using previously [documented methods](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254226/core-updates-after-install-with-composer-create-project-drupal-drupal) to remove the replace block in composer.json and move the drupal/core require statement to update drupal/core.

However, I'm now running into a strange issue with a very specific Contributed Module that is detecting the `"name": "drupal/drupal" statement and version as 1.0, which then conflicts with dependencies it wants to install. I tried removing the name field since composer docs state it is only required for published packages, but this does not help resolve it.

Some other [google results](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2638856) suggest that my drupal core is missing a .git repo that may be required to detect versions? How would I resolve this if it's the case? What else can I try?

Error, caused by `composer require drupal/csv_serialization`:

```
  Problem 1
    - remove drupal/drupal No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)|remove drupal/core 8.6.1
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.1|remove drupal/drupal No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.1|remove drupal/drupal No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)
    - Installation request for drupal/drupal No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - Installation request for drupal/core (locked at 8.6.1, required as ^8.6) -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.6.1].
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "drupal/drupal",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
        "drupal/core": "^8.6",
        "drush/drush": "^9.4",
        "symfony/http-kernel": "^3.4",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "^3.4"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
    },
    "extra": {
        "_readme": [
            "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
            "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
            "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
            "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
            "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
        ],
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "core/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": true,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-extra": false
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "post-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess",
        "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade-check": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::upgradePHPUnit",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade": "@composer update phpunit/phpunit --with-dependencies --no-progress",
        "phpcs": "phpcs --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --",
        "phpcbf": "phpcbf --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is supposed to help. https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal

Comment: Also try adding `"conflict": { "drupal/drupal": "*" }`. You  may need to change the `name` of your package to make that work

Comment: "There are a few tools that attempt to convert your existing Drupal codebase to a Composer-managed codebase (e.g. composerize-drupal, or Drupal Console's composerize command), but I have found them to be a little more trouble than they are worth. I recommend rebuilding the codebase from scratch, like I do in this guide." Source: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/converting-non-composer-drupal-codebase-use-composer

Comment: @Kevin If you would like to provide you answer with whatever context might be helpful to the next person, I'll accept it, it worked quite well on a minimal site install. It should be noted that more than likely the desired default command would be `composer composerize-drupal --no-update`, because it also moved me from 8.6.1 to 8.6.3. So I did a `git reset --hard` and then ran again with that to more preferable results. I prefer to keep my git commits tied to one single intention, so I'll run core updates later.

Comment: I haven't actually used it to turn a tarball installed project into a totally composer controlled one, so I am not 100% on the outcome, but I know a colleague at work was able to do it. Did it work for you?

Comment: @Kevin Yes it worked for me. I was able to run `composer require drupal/csv_serialization` and get it installed quite easily. I don't know the exact pedigree of our project because it was created from a template that has all the modules set up the way the team likes, but has that major flaw of still relying on manual installation of modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool that helps convert old style Drupal 8 installs to composer managed ones: https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal

This should help restructure the project to leverage Composer, which the vanilla tarball install is not geared toward.