# How to successfully follow Drupal.org's instructions for updating via composer

Tags: composer

In following the instructions at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer, prior to updating core from 8.5.3 to 8.6.12, when I attempt to go through the list of available module updates

```
composer outdated "drupal/*
```

the very first update:

```
composer update drupal/admin_toolbar --with-dependencies
```

results in:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.12|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.12|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
    - Installation request for drupal/drupal dev-master -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal[dev-master].
    - Installation request for drupal/core (locked at 8.6.12, required as ^8.6) -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.6.12].
```

Following are the contents of my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "drupal/drupal",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0+",
    "require": {
    "drupal/core": "^8.6",
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "~1.3",
        "drupal/console": "~1.0",
        "drupal/migrate_d2d": "3.x-dev",
        "drupal/codesnippet": "^1.6",
        "drupal/nexus": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/social_media_links": "^2.2",
        "drupal/twitter_block": "^2.1",
        "drupal/nocaptcha_recaptcha": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/adsense": "^1.0",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.0",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.19",
        "drupal/recaptcha": "^2.2",
        "drupal/blazy": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/calendar": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/computed_field": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/crop": "^1.2",
        "drupal/date": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/dropzonejs": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/embed": "^1.0",
        "drupal/entity_browser": "^1.1",
        "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/image_widget_crop": "^2.0",
        "drupal/languageicons": "1.0-beta1",
        "drupal/media_entity_document": "^1.1",
        "drupal/media_entity_image": "^1.2",
        "drupal/media_entity_instagram": "^1.4",
        "drupal/media_entity_slideshow": "^1.2",
        "drupal/media_entity_twitter": "^1.3",
        "drupal/scheduler": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/simple_gmap": "^1.3",
        "drupal/views_field_view": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/views_php": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/webform": "^5.0@beta",
        "drush/drush": "9.0.0-beta7",
        "drupal/social_login": "2.72",
        "drupal/likebtn": "^2.13",
        "drupal/drupal8_zymphonies_theme": "^1.3"
    },
    "replace": {
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
    },
    "extra": {
        "_readme": [
            "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
            "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
            "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
            "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
            "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
        ],
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "core/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": false,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-extra": false
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "post-autoload-dump": [
          "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess"
        ],
        "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `composer update --with-dependencies`? Maybe you also can fix your issue by removing your lockfile first.

Comment: With regards to just doing the global update, there are recommendations all over the place (including on D.O.) that doing the contrib modules first is preferable.

Comment: You do have your site locally? And update that first, do you? You have a backup of your database and your code checked in Git, right? So just try it out. And when it doesn't work, simply restore everything.

Comment: Removing the lock file changed nothing. Attempting the global update...

Comment: composer update --with-dependencies results in a longer but similar list of problems, essentially identifying each higher version of Drupal core as "don't install"

Comment: And what's with `composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies` as suggested on DO?

Comment: Seems you never added `composer require webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --dev` in the first place, no? Your composer.json could need some improvements. Like sorting packages alphabetically and fix indentation.

Comment: The webflo suggestion you cite is for those who began with drupal-composer/drupal-project, which I didn't do.

Comment: Maybe remove your lockfile AND the vendor folder and run `composer clearcache` prior to updating.

Comment: That resulted in the same, but I did find a reference to the issue with a resolution that works. Adding answer.

Comment: The possible duplicate starts with: "At our company we have several sites that appear to have been made using the now deprecated method of composer create-project drupal/drupal ...". I think this is a 100% duplicate when looking at the composer.json.

Comment: What is causing the issue and the issue are the same in both the questions. You even linked the other question in the answer.

Comment: No, I linked a question titled “How to concert a Drupal site to work with composer.” That question is asked when you have a Drupal site installed without using composer and want to subsequently have composer manage it. My question was about a site installed with composer but won’t update.

Comment: _The issue is discussed in [this issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272797/converting-a-drupal-drupal-site-to-work-with-composer) and the composer command project mentioned in it, here resolved my issue._ It means you found the solution on the other question, which for us means this question duplicates the other one. It doesn't matter if Composer was used from the beginning, or the site was converted to using Composer later. The cause of the issue is the same in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, in part or in whole, turns out to be related to the d.o. instructions to create the composer implementation with drupal/drupal. This doesn't work when then subsequently updating.

The issue is discussed in [this issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272797/converting-a-drupal-drupal-site-to-work-with-composer) and the composer command project mentioned in it, [here](https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal) resolved my issue.

Comment: That does present as the same cause, but not as the same symptom, ie if the question regards converting a site not managed by composer to one that is, what would cause someone to read it if, like me, their site was set up with composer originally, unless they just start reading all questions with descriptions that present a fringe contextual connection?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and the only solution I found working was to use an older version of composer.

I downloaded [composer 1.7.2](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and installed it at `/usr/local/bin/composer1.7.2` and than I was able to run

```
composer1.7.2 update --with-dependencies
```

Which run without any problems.

I picked this tip from [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2019-01-20/composer-update-issue-867) but I had not seen [this one](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3020337) which seems to propose a different workaround which might be worth a try.